# Laravel Query with subquery not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Maybe I am doing this incorrectly, however what I want to do logically is this:

I want to first select all posts that contain a certain string.

Then from those results, I want to narrow it down to only posts within a certain date (Y|m|d).

So this is what im doing at the moment:

```
$results = DB::table('posts');

if ($query == null){
  $query = "Posted On: " . $date;
}else {
  $results->where('posts.title', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
          ->orWhere('posts.meta_description', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
          ->orWhere('posts.meta_keywords', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
          ->orWhere('posts.body', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
          ->orWhere('posts.seo_title', 'LIKE', "%$query%");
  $query = $query." / Posted On: " . $date;
}


$results->where(function($query) use ($date){

  $date = explode('-', $date);
  if (!isset($date[1])){
    $query->whereYear('created_at', '=', $date[0]);
  }else if(isset($date[1]) && !isset($date[2])){
    $query->whereYear('created_at', '=', $date[0])
          ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $date[1]);
  }else if (isset($date[1]) && isset($date[2])){
    $query->whereYear('created_at', '=', $date[0])
          ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $date[1])
          ->whereDay('created_at', '=', $date[2]);
  }
});

$results = $results->paginate($this->paginate_size());
```

However, this query is still just returning anything that contains the query string and ignoring the fact that I want to select a subset that are only posts on a specific year/month/day.

What am I missing?

Edit:

Using $results->toSql(); I get the query:

```
select * from `posts` where `posts`.`title` LIKE ? or 
`posts`.`meta_description` LIKE ? or `posts`.`meta_keywords` LIKE ? or 
`posts`.`body` LIKE ? or `posts`.`seo_title` LIKE ? and year(`created_at`) = ?
```

However, it is not working...

If I enter for example the query "Lorem" it will find all of the posts with the text Lorem in it.

However, when I add a specific date like just "2015", it should not show ANY posts from 2015 with the query Lorem since it does not exist.

So there is some logic problem here. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please display the query that laravel execute (using ->toSql() )

Comment: You should set `$results` to the value returned by the where function. So `$results = $results->where(...`

Comment: The query I get is :

Comment: The query I get is :  `select * from `posts` where `posts`.`title` LIKE ? or `posts`.`meta_description` LIKE ? or `posts`.`meta_keywords` LIKE ? or `posts`.`body` LIKE ? or `posts`.`seo_title` LIKE ? and year(`created_at`) = ? `

Comment: The problem is that the query completely ignores the "Date" - so i I search for "Lorem" it will find 2 posts with the text Lorem, but if I specify the date being 2015, it should find 0 posts since there are no posts in 2015 with the text "lorem"

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need a subquery.

If you have the proper query in place you should be able to access in the same query.

Of course you can have the dynamic where with the conditions, but do it on the same query. Something along the lines, for example:

```
if ($query == null){
  $query = "Posted On: " . $date;
}

$results->where('posts.title', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
        ->orWhere('posts.meta_description', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
        ->orWhere('posts.meta_keywords', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
        ->orWhere('posts.body', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
        ->orWhere('posts.seo_title', 'LIKE', "%$query%");

$date = explode('-', $date);
if (!isset($date[1])){
  $results->whereYear('created_at', '=', $date[0]);
}else if(isset($date[1]) && !isset($date[2])){
  $results->whereYear('created_at', '=', $date[0])
          ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $date[1]);
}else if (isset($date[1]) && isset($date[2])){
  $results->whereYear('created_at', '=', $date[0])
          ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $date[1])
          ->whereDay('created_at', '=', $date[2]);
}

$results = $results->paginate($this->paginate_size());
```

Comment: I have actually tried this before, and it has the same results... the problem is that the query completely ignores the "Date" - so i I search for "Lorem" it will find 2 posts with the text Lorem, but if I specify the date being 2015, it should find 0 posts since there are no posts in 2015 with the text "lorem"

Comment: I updated my original question to include the SQL... which is: select * from `posts` where `posts`.`title` LIKE ? or 
`posts`.`meta_description` LIKE ? or `posts`.`meta_keywords` LIKE ? or 
`posts`.`body` LIKE ? or `posts`.`seo_title` LIKE ? and year(`created_at`) = ?

Comment: Have you looked at what inside of `$date[0]` does it work when you run this query manually. this sql looks fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use the whereDate() Eloquent method:

```
$results = DB::table('posts');
if ($query == null){
  $query = "Posted On: " . $date;
}else {
  $results->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('posts.title', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
          ->orWhere('posts.meta_description', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
          ->orWhere('posts.meta_keywords', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
          ->orWhere('posts.body', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
          ->orWhere('posts.seo_title', 'LIKE', "%$query%");
  })->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d');
  $query = $query." / Posted On: " . $date;
}
$results = $results->paginate($this->paginate_size());
```